# Как сделать меню которое отодвигает контент в bootstrap offcanvas

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Закрывает текст, хотелось чтобы при открытии меню отодвигался текст
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вот так всё равно. Даже если position использовать
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял то position: absolute или fixed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

И анимировать это дело.

Comment: Не помогает. Всё равно при открытии текст под списком находится

Comment: @Кирил, что именно вы хотите сделать?) 

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/offcanvas/#live-demo точно такое же повидение должно быть?

Comment: @Кирилл, так хотите сделать? https://codepen.io/dima0508-the-looper/pen/RwYjXRP

Comment: Нет, хочу чтобы при открытии бургера контент после открытия бургера сдвигался вправо.